# How do I display to the user when the nodeJS server is reachable using socketIO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io

I am making a web app that shows the user when the server is reachable so they can post data. Currently it works with the code I am using but I am having an issue when another user connects / disconnects it directly affects another client that is connected.

NodeJS code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Connected');
    io.emit('Connect');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Connection Lost');
        io.emit('disconnect');
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
     socket.on('disconnect', function(){
              $('#connection').html('disconnected');
              document.getElementById(id = 'save_button').style.display = "none"
              document.getElementById(id = 'not_save_button').style.display = "block"
          });

          socket.on('Connect',function() {
            $('#connection').html('connected');
            document.getElementById(id = 'save_button').style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById(id = 'not_save_button').style.display = "none"
          });
```

So basically I am trying to make each page only listen to the server. It currently works perfectly with just one client but when you add anything else to the system it can't function.

I have tried socket ID but these get updated when the server reconnects so I couldn't find a way to make these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('Connected');
    socket.emit('Connect');

});

io.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Connection Lost');
    socket.emit('disconnect');
});
```

Using Amit's answer I managed to find a solution.

Comment: Is that what you ended up using? Does it work? It looks like incomplete and probably exception-throwing code

Comment: Yeah this is what I am currently using in the code and it is working as I want it with no exceptions.

Comment: What does `socket` (the one you call `emit` on...) refer to in the disconnect handler? It's not defined in your fragment

Answer (score 0):

The [`Server.emit`](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit) function emits the message to all clients. To send to a specific client, use the [`Socket.emit`](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#emit(name:string[,-%E2%80%A6]):socket) method of the relevant socket. In your case:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('Connected');
  socket.emit('Connect');

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Connection Lost');
});
```

Comment: This crashes the server when I close the second page.

Comment: @onemillion - Sorry, I didn't notice what the code was actually doing. It makes no sense to emit on a disconnected socket and that's probably why your server crashes. Removed that part. What are you trying to emit on such an event?

Comment: I am trying to show to the user that the server is disconnected so that's why I have the emit on disconnect.

Comment: @onemillion - You don't need any server code for that, and as I wrote earlier, you won't be able to emit anything from the server on a disconnected socket. Your client code that listens for disconnect event should be enough. Infact, you probably don't need to emit anything on connection as well, client should be able to identify that locally (using `on('connect')`)

Comment: @onemillion - why do you keep changing your accepted answer? Are you somehow "not happy" with mine?

Comment: I thought I would post the correct answer in-case anybody wants to fix this problem in the future.